# NSRange : incorrect behavior. Why?

Tags: iphone, nsrange

range.location should be 0. Am i right ?

```
NSRange range;
range = [@"beer" rangeOfString:@"beer and vodka"];
if (range.location== NSNotFound)
{
    NSLog(@"Why?");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you search for a string "beer and vodka" in "beer" string - obviously that longer string is not present in the shorter one, so you get expected output. What you need should probably be vice versa:

```
NSRange range = [@"beer and vodka" rangeOfString:@"beer"];
if (range.location == NSNotFound)
{
    NSLog(@"Why?");
}
```